# Couldn't lock the profile file error in MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, intune

Working on migrating the Xamarin Forms app to .NET MAUI.
The app gets freezed after certain steps and do not load the inital page also.
There is no error nor exception.
This app includes the latest Intune Android SDK for MAUI.
But when we see the build log there is a line as below.

[.archxtractPus] Couldn't lock the profile file /data/misc/profiles/cur/0/jp.co.cegb.archxtractPush/primary.prof: Failed to open file '/data/misc/profiles/cur/0/jp.co.cegb.archxtractPush/primary.prof': Permission denied
[.archxtractPus] Could not forcefully load profile /data/misc/profiles/cur/0/jp.co.cegb.archxtractPush/primary.prof
[Native] Failed to change file encryption with err 0x31455010000000d during open with op 1
[Native] File we failed to change encryption on is %s

Can anyone please explain and help resolving it.

Comment: when you have a wierd case of no errors shown you might think about deleting all the bin/obj folders, restart visual studio and rebuild..

Comment: No luck even after doing that!

Comment: what also helps is run on different platforms, on one of them you might get a clue on the blocker.. ios, windows, droid..